# Recover unknown raid setup

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid

I have 2 disks, they are the same make, model + size.
Both of them have Linux RAID partitions on them.
I *think* they used to be in a software raid1 array together, but I am hesitant to just jump in and try to recreate the array in case I inadvertently cause data loss.
Most of the data that was on these disks is backed up already, but not all. If at all possible I'd prefer not to lose anything that isn't already lost.

YAST has detected that there used to be an array, but it only added 1 of the 2 disks to the "array", and when I tried to mount the array it seemed to think there are no partitions present.

I tried to used mdadm to scan, but it gives:

```
sudo mdadm --assemble --scan
mdadm: Found some drive for an array that is already active: /dev/md/RedRaid1
mdadm: giving up.
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
```

and fdisk of the "array" gives the following:

```
> sudo fdisk /dev/md127 
[sudo] password for root: 

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.33.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

The old ext4 signature will be removed by a write command.

Device does not contain a recognized partition table.
The size of this disk is 3.7 TiB (4000784908288 bytes). DOS partition table format cannot be used on drives for volumes larger than 2199023255040 bytes for 512-byte sectors. Use GUID partition table format (GPT).

Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0xa8841205.

Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/md127: 3.7 TiB, 4000784908288 bytes, 7814033024 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa8841205

Command (m for help): q

lee@linux-e9uw:~>
```

I've included below some screenshots from various partitioning screens in yast.

How can I discover and be confident about what is on the 2 disks and reassemble them into whatever form they used to be in?

[image: All disks in yast]
[image: sdb1]
[image: sdc1]
[image: RedRaid1]
[image: used devices]
[image: Partitions]

Comment: While writing this Q I noticed something about the fdisk output:
`The old ext4 signature will be removed by a write command.` 
So on I tried to mount /dev/md127 directly - successfully! There is no partition table and the entire "array" is formatted directly with ext4.
So I am actually able to read the data on _1_ of the disks, but I still have no idea about the other.

This data suggests that there was no striping involved with the array. I still need to at least verify that the other disk _used_ to be part of the same array so that I can wipe it and add it back in?

Comment: If the disks were part of a raid set, then the fact that you can mount a single disk AND you get a valid file-system suggests that, at least that first disk, was either not a raid member at all or part of a mirror /RAID1. If that second disk was part of the same mirror, you should also be able to mount it and see the same directory structure and identical data.

Comment: Except what I mounted was the md device, not the underlying partition. For the other disk there is now md device to mount

Comment: @DJL Well, a RAID1 array can consist of a single disk - since it's just a mirror. I mean it just cannot be anything else. If it's RAID0, it'd be just gibberish. RAID5-6? Just parity or gibberish. RAID10? Same as RAID0, since now you have half of the data (implying 4 disks were in the array.)

Comment: Yes, that's all well and good. But how can I be sure that the other disk is formerly the other half of the raid1, and thus safe to overwrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mdadm --examine` on the partitions `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdc1` to display information about the RAID superblock.  This will tell you the Array UUID and what slot the drive was in in the array.  For example:

```
#  mdadm  --examine /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 822697f0:058006d2:f0233a55:c6504b36
           Name : localhost.localdomain:0  (local to host localhost.localdomain)
  Creation Time : Wed Jul  3 16:22:07 2019
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 2095104 (1023.00 MiB 1072.69 MB)
     Array Size : 1047552 (1023.00 MiB 1072.69 MB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=1968 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : ce3cd8fd:a1f3626c:9f8152cf:9a8cc0bc

    Update Time : Wed Jul  3 16:22:43 2019
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : ba1d5d65 - correct
         Events : 17


   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

In recovery situations like yours, it's very likely that the array wasn't properly stopped, or that someone assembled the thing with only one drive.  If the kernel moved the array's sequence number forward, then you're not going to be able to assemble it cleanly with both drives.

As @Shiki and @HBruijn have said, it's likely a mirrored RAID 1.  Otherwise, you wouldn't have been able to assemble it and mount that filesystem.  If all you need is the data, then just copy it off.  If you need to re-form the array, then verify that the other partition was actually part of the same array.  If it was, you can add it as a spare with `mdadm -a`.

Comment: Well thats very interesting. preparing to run the commands you suggested I first used yast to check the device allocations (I've removed sda since the question was originally asked). I was surprised to see that yast now shows both drives in the array. Running your commands confirms that the UUIDs are the same.
`mdadm --misc --detail /dev/md127` says the array is clean, but `mdadm --monitor /dev/md127` says a rebuild is in progress.I'll keep an eye on it.